# CSS Hex to Shorthand Hex conversion

Tags: css, algorithm, math, hex

What is the proper algorithm to convert Hex to Shorthand Hex? For example: `#996633` easily is converted to `#963`. But what if it's something like `#F362C3`?

My first guess would be that I just take the first value of each color and go with that. So `#F362C3` becomes `#F6C`. But I don't know how to mathematically justify that approach.

```
function hex_to_shorthand($hex, $uppercase=true)
{
  // Remove preceding hash if present
  if ($hex[0] == "#") $hex = substr($hex, 1);
  
  // If it already is shorthand, nothing more to do here
  if (strlen($hex) == 3) return "#$hex";
  
  // If it is not 6 characters long then it is invalid
  elseif (strlen($hex) !== 6) return "";
  
  // The final shorthand HEX value
  $final = "";
  
  // Get the triplets
  $triplets = str_split($hex, 2);
  
  // Go over each triplet separately
  foreach ($triplets as $t)
  {
    // Get the decimal equivalent of triplet
    $dec = base_convert($t, 16, 10);
    
    // Find the remainder
    $remainder = $dec % 17;
    
    // Go to the nearest decimal that will yield a double nibble
    $new = ($dec%17 > 7) ? 17+($dec-$remainder) : $dec-$remainder;
    
    // Convert decimal into HEX
    $hex = base_convert($new, 10, 16);
    
    // Add one of the two identical nibbles
    $final .= $hex[0];
  }
  // Return the shorthand HEX colour value
  return $uppercase ? strtoupper($final) : strtolower($final);
}
```

This seems a little more involved and again, I'm not sure what the mathematical justification is behind it. So something like `#F362C3` becomes `#E6C`, which is not what I would expect.

What the proper way to do this and what is the mathematical proof behind how the conversion works?

(The above code is PHP but that can apply to any language)

Comment: What didn't you expect? `e` in the shorthand notation stands for `ee` (dec 238). `f3` (243) is closer to `ee` than it is to `ff` (255). The justification is more or less the same as rounding decimals on the five.

Comment: The code above should also make up its mind whether it returns the shorthand colour code with or without a leading hash sign.

Comment: That is a really good point M Oehm. I didn't look at it this way.

Comment: This code is faulty, the "> 7" should be  "> 8"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code above is **correct** and **efficient**, having a time complexity: **O(1)**.

You need to obtain the nearest color for the initial color.

Because there is an RGB code, every **color** can be considered a **point** that has integer coordinates (between 0 and 255) in a **3D space**:

```
- R -> OX
- G -> OY
- B -> OZ
```

### Purpose

Identify the point `P'(r',g',b')` (output) which is the closest point to `P(r,g,b)` (input) where:

```
- r', g', b' are in {0=0x00, 17=0x11, 34=0x22, ... 255=0xff}
(because only 0x?? can be reduced to ? in CSS, where 0x represents base 16)
- r, g, b are in {0,1,2,3, ..., 255}
```

What does it mean ? We want the **minimum distance between P and P' in a 3D space**.

So, we want `D = sqrt( (r-r')^2 + (g-g')^2 + (b-b')^2 )` to be minimum. This is the distance between 2 points in a 3D space.

**Obs**:

Every member is `>= 0`.

So, if we want a minimum `D` => we want:

- a minimum `|r-r'|`
- a minimum `|g-g'|`
- a minimum `|b-b'|`

So, the problem boils down to: find the closest hexadecimal number of 2 identical characters that is closest to a given hexadecimal number.

As you can see, we have an even number of numbers between xx and yy => there is no number at the same distance of xx and yy (where `y=x+1`) => we don't need to approximate anything (E.g.: we know for sure that 08 is closer to 00 than to 11.):

```
00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08 -> close to 00
09, 0A, 0B, 0C, 0D, 0E, 0F, 10, 11 -> close to 11

11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 -> close to 11
1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E, 1F, 20, 21, 22 -> close to 22

...
```

**Question**: Is the solution unique?

We are asking this question because `(r-r')^2 = min` can be achieved in 2 different ways:

- `r-r1'= sqrt(min)`
- `r-r2'=-sqrt(min)`

We demonstrate it only for `r'` because the other colors are similar.

We can show the uniqueness using 2 different methods:

1. Let's add the lines above:

   `r1' + r2' = 2*r`

   where `r1'=xx, r2'=yy => r = zz = (x+y)/2(x+y)/2 in (00, ..., ff)`
   but because `r'-r` is minimum and `r=zz` => `r'=zz` => `r1'=r2'` => **unique solution**
2. Based on the examples above the question, if we consider a number, we can't find 2 different numbers `r1'=xx` and `r2'=yy` having `r-r1'`=`r2'-r` because `r` is closer to one of them. It can be at the same distance only if `r=zz`, but in this case `r` can be used as `r'` (because `r'` had to look like `zz` and to have the minimum distance => a 0 distance is quite perfect). => we don't have 2 solutions (`r1'=r2'`) => **unique solution**

Analogue for g', b' => **P'(r',g',b') is unique** ( there is no point as close to P as P' ).

---

You can also see a **Java code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "#F362C3";
    System.out.println(hexToShort(s));
}

private static String hexToShort(String hex) {

    // if it is short, return
    if ( hex.length() == 4 ){
        return hex;
    }

    // remove #
    if ( hex.charAt(0) == '#' ) {
        hex = hex.substring(1);
    }

    // check that hex is valid
    if ( hex.length() != 6 ) {
        return "";
    }

    String r = hex.substring(0,2);
    String g = hex.substring(2,4);
    String b = hex.substring(4,6);

    return "#" + shortVal(r) + shortVal(g) + shortVal(b);

}

private static String shortVal(String c) {
    int ci = Integer.parseInt(c, 16);
    return Integer.toString((ci%17 > 7) ? (17+ci-ci%17) : (ci-ci%17), 16).substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Actually the code does not correspond to the example you're giving.

You say that 19 is closer to 1, but the code spits out 2.

Answer (score 0):

I made a JavaScript equivalent. It also works for RGBA.

My math is simpler and also more accurate as the php and Java version is shifted 1 to the left.

On the range of 256, there are 17 colors between each gaps ie: from "cc" to "dd" and 9 colors on each edge converting to "0" or "f". So (17x14 + 9x2) = 256

```js
function shorthand(hex) {
  if (hex.length%2==0 && parseInt(hex,16)) {
      let a = []
    for (let i=0;i<=(hex.length-1)/2;i++) {
      a.push(parseInt(hex.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16))
      a[i] = Math.round(a[i] / 17).toString(16)
    }
    return a.join('')
   }
}




function print(hex) {
  window.div.textContent = shorthand(hex);
  window.div.style = `background-color:#${shorthand(hex)}`
}
```

```css
div {width: 10em}
div:before {content: '#'}
```

```html
<p>Insert RGB or RGBa</p>
#<input type="text" id="in" name="in" value="f4a9b34f">
<div id="div"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="print(window.in.value)">convert</button>
```