# How to compress a html color code properly?

Tags: html, colors, compression

Hi I am storing html color codes as strings in my sql database.

e.g. a html color usually have 7 characters, e.g. "#f5f6f0", 
and a database field called "colors" consists of dozens of these colors in one string, such as "#f5f6f0 #e3e5e6 #3c2d5e ..."

Right now I felt it took too much space and wanted to compress it using a simple and easy to understand method, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Store them as integers. Something like `(r << 16) + (g << 8) + b`. Or potentially array of 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

A database column should never contain multiple values.
You need a 2nd table:

Let's say your table was called records, and the id called record_id.  If you need multiple colors, you should have a second table called record_colors, with a combined PK on that table of (
   record_id FK from the 1st table,
   color
).

Answer (score 0):

Try using shorthand hex colors when possible.

.dark-yellow {color:#ffcc00;}
.dark-yellow {color:#fc0;}

[CSS Hex to Shorthand Hex conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607844/css-hex-to-shorthand-hex-conversion)